# Can someone help invent an expression for this situation?

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

I'm stuck for an expression that describes this example, which is similar to a "self-fulfilling prophecy" but is more complicated:

> Someone claims, falsely, to be a dentist. Someone who likes
>   that person, but doesn't realize he's not really a dentist, claims,
>   falsely, that the guy did a fantastic job on his implants. He's sure
>   his friend *would* do a fantastic job, he just needs a "helping hand" to
>   get started.

So it's not "a prediction that causes itself to become true", it's "a little white lie that unwittingly advances a deception". "Self-serving" (one's own interests, often in disregard of the truth) is close but in this case there's no "self" in the action.

Not sure if my question is off-topic, but it's like [**this one**](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/how-can-i-express-this-more-clearly-or-concisely).

Comment: The question you link to is four years old, and no longer considered an example of a good question on this site. This question is asking what to write, which is off-topic here. Closing, but perhaps you can edit this into a better question? More information about this site is available in our site [tour].

Comment: OK. I moved the question to English usage (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269236/is-there-a-neat-expression-for-this-situation)